# Remove second occurrence of value from array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, duplicates

Instead of removing the first occurrence of a duplicated value, as my code currently does, how can I get it to delete the second occurrence instead?

```
namespace deletenumber
{
    class Program
    {    
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {

            Random r = new Random();

            int[] a = new int[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                a[i] = r.Next(1, 100);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(" a [" + i + "] = " + a[i]);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What number do you want to delete?");
            int item = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();

            int index = Array.IndexOf(a, item);
            a = a.Where((b, c) => c != index).ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", a));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always reveal when you are submitting homework as a task, you should show what you have tried, and how you are unit testing. You do none of this.

Comment: @MortenBork let's please be more patient against new users. This is why [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) post exist.

Comment: @McCloud54 please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask questions in SO.

Comment: It is unknown what the real task is. You may be asked to actually remove the second instance of that number (not the third or however many more there might be), also you may be asked to do this using constant space, and also in the most efficient way. In that sense, the question leaves too much to the imagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why exactly you might want to delete only the second occurrence because there should be no matter which one of the duplicates is removed, correct?

Anyway, there are several ways of achieving what you want.
I will not directly write a solution here, but will propose the methods you can use in order to achieve what you want:

1. [Array.LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.lastindexof?view=netcore-3.1#:%7E:text=Operations%20in%20Arrays-,LastIndexOf(Array%2C%20Object%2C%20Int32%2C%20Int32),ends%20at%20the%20specified%20index.)
2. Use the same `IndexOf` method again to find the second occurrence, by starting the search from the previous occurrence (`myArray.IndexOf("string", last_indexof_index);`)

---

Generally, consider using a `HashSet<T>` (official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1)) if you want to have a collection of unique elements.

You can also convert your existing collection to `HashSet<int>`:

```cs
int[] a = new int[10];
var set = new HashSet<int>(a);
```

Comment: Notice that the first solution will not remove the second occurrence but the last. So if you had 3 or more occurrences of the number it would always remove the last one but not explicitly the second.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your array to a List and then just remove the index before casting it back to an array:

```
var list = new List<int>(a);
list.RemoveAt(index);
a = list.ToArray();
```